# how can I efficiently add arrays of differing lengths to a df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have thousands of arrays of differing lengths (daily data) which I want to add to a "master" df by the dates. I am currently doing this via the below code. Data is a list of lists with the first list e.g i[0] referring to the specified identifier and i[1] being a dictionary of values and data points related to the specific identifier.

```
for i in data:
    identifier = i[0]
    obs = i[1]["obs"]
    dates = i[1]["dates"]   
    tempDf = pd.DataFrame(obs, index = dates, columns = [identifier])
    tempDf.index = tempDf.index.map(str)    
    masterDF=pd.merge(masterDF, tempDf, how = 'outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

This is really really slow showing a significant performance drop after a thousand or so iterations. What is the best way to improve the performance? I am thinking about trying to just write the enitre code base in numpy but I like the use of pandas to check stuff later on and to graph stuff in the future (i am not that experienced with matplot lib).

A simple example of the code would be to have these 3 dfs where 1,2,3 etc are index dates.

masterdf:

```
  col1,col2, col3
1,x,y,z
2,x,y,z
3,x,y,z
4,x,y,z
5,x,y,z
6,x,y,z
7,x,y,z
```

df1:

```
  df1
5,x
6,x
7,x
```

df2:

```
  df2
2,y
3,y
4,y
5,y
6,y
7,y
```

desired output:

```
   col1 col2  col3  df1  df2
1     x    y     z  NaN  NaN
2     x    y     z  NaN    y
3     x    y     z  NaN    y
4     x    y     z  NaN    y
5     x    y     z    x    y
6     x    y     z    x    y
7     x    y     z    x    y
```

Comment: Try concatenation: `pd.concat((masterdf, df1, df2), axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `concat`. To extract the data from your `data` list, maybe this would do it

```
res = pd.concat(
    [masterDF]
    + [pd.DataFrame(vals['obs'], index=vals['dates'], columns=[identifier])
      for identifier, vals in data],
    axis=1
)
```